# ¿Cómo se envían los datos del formulario de login al controller?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Tengo una página de login donde el cliente se loguea y este va a la bbdd a comprobar si los datos introducidos corresponden a un email y a un password.

Al intentarlo, me retorna constantemente -introduciendo los datos correctos- a login?error.
Este es el formulario que tengo en el archivo iniciarsesion.html

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Iniciar sesi&oacute;n</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <form action="#" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${cliente}" method="post">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger text-center"  th:if="${param.error}" role="alert">
                                    Usuario o contraseña incorrectos
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Usuario:</label>
                                    <input id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce tu email..." name="username" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Contrase&ntilde;a:</label>
                                    <input id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce tu contrase&ntilde;a..." name="password" type="password">
                                </div>

                                <input id="login-submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit"
                                       value="Iniciar sesi&oacute;n"/>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <p class="text-center">¿No tienes una cuenta? Reg&iacute;strate <a class="registro" href="register">aqu&iacute;</a>.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer text-center text-white">
        <p>Euro-construcciones 08830, S.L.<br> C/Trencapinyes 54, 08818 Olivella (Barcelona)
            615969008
            <a href="mailto:euro_construcciones@hotmail.com">Euro_construcciones@hotmail.com</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el controlador LoginController, donde le paso el objeto 'cliente'.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@GetMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    return "iniciarsesion";
}

@PostMapping("/login")
public String nuevoLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("cliente") Cliente cliente, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
        return "iniciarsesion";
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}

public String logout() {
    return "";
}

public String logingFailed() {
    return "";
}
```

}

Debería pasar email y contraseña de forma independiente en lugar de mandarlo como  un solo objeto?

Por si hiciera falta, coloco aquí también mi WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/", "/about", "/gallery", "/register", "/css/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin((form) -> form
            .loginPage("/login")
            .successHandler(successHandler())
            .permitAll()
        );
    return http.build();
}

private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
    return simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

Los clientes se registran en la bbdd a través de un formulario, donde les paso el cliente como objeto.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Formulario de registro</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${cliente}" method="POST">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Cliente</label>
                                    <input th:field="*{nombre}" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre y apellidos..." type="text" required />
                                    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nombre')}" th:errors="*{nombre}"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Direcci&oacute;n de correo electr&oacute;nico</label>
                                    <input th:field="*{correo}" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce tu correo..." type="email" required />
                                    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('correo')}" th:errors="*{correo}"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Tel&eacute;fono</label>
                                    <input th:field="*{tlf}" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce tu n&uacute;mero..." type="tel" required />
                                    <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('tlf')}" th:errors="*{tlf}"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
                                    <input th:field="*{passwd}" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce tu contrase&ntilde;a..." type="password" required/>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Confirmar contrase&ntilde;a</label>
                                    <input th:field="*{confirm}" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirma tu contrase&ntilde;a..." type="password" required/>
                                </div>
                                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit"
                                       value="Registrarme"/>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer text-center text-white">
        <p>Euro-construcciones 08830, S.L.<br> C/Trencapinyes 54, 08818 Olivella (Barcelona)
            615969008
            <a href="mailto:euro_construcciones@hotmail.com">Euro_construcciones@hotmail.com</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Y aquí es donde viene al RegistroController:

```
@Controller
public class RegistroController {

@Autowired
private ClienteService clienteService;

@GetMapping("/register")
public String registro(Model model) {
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    model.addAttribute(cliente);
    return "registro";
}

@PostMapping("/register")
public String nuevoCliente (@Valid @ModelAttribute("cliente") Cliente cliente, BindingResult result) {

    if (cliente.getConfirm().equals(cliente.getPasswd())) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(cliente.getPasswd());
        cliente.setPasswd(encodedPassword);
        
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordConfirmEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPasswordConfirm = passwordConfirmEncoder.encode(cliente.getConfirm());
        cliente.setConfirm(encodedPasswordConfirm);
    }
    
    
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registro";
    }
    clienteService.save(cliente);
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si hiciera falta también comparto mi Service y Repository así como la entidad Cliente y UserDetailsService:

Clase ClienteService:

```
public interface ClienteService {

    public Iterable<Cliente> findAll();

    public Page<Cliente> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    public Cliente findById(Long id);

    public Cliente save(Cliente cliente);

    public void deleteById(Long id);

    boolean existsUsuarioPorCorreo(String correo);

    Cliente findByCorreo(String correo);
}
```

ClienteServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class ClienteServiceImpl implements ClienteService {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    @Override
    public Iterable<Cliente> findAll() {
        return clienteRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Cliente> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return clienteRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Override
    public Cliente findById(Long id) {
        Optional<Cliente> cliente = clienteRepository.findById(id);
        if (cliente.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return cliente.get();
    }

    @Override
    public Cliente save(Cliente cliente) {
        return clienteRepository.save(cliente);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        clienteRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean existsUsuarioPorCorreo(String correo) {
        return clienteRepository.existsByCorreo(correo);
    }

    @Override
    public Cliente findByCorreo(String correo) {
        return clienteRepository.findByCorreo(correo);
    }

}
```

ClienteRepository:

```
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Long>{

    boolean existsByCorreo(String correo);

    Cliente findByCorreo(String correo);

}
```

Entidad Cliente:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clientes")
public class Cliente implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id_cliente;

    @NotEmpty(message="No puede estar vacío")
    private String nombre;

    @NotEmpty(message="No puede estar vacío")
    @Email(message="Introduce una correcta dirección de correo")
    @Column(name="mail", nullable=false, length = 50, unique = true)
    private String correo;

    @NotEmpty(message="No puede estar vacío")
    @Column(name = "telefono", length = 9)
    private int tlf;

    @NotEmpty(message="No puede estar vacío")
    private String passwd;

    @NotEmpty(message="No puede estar vacío")
    private String confirm;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "clientes_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
              name = "id_cliente", referencedColumnName = "id_cliente"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
              name = "id_rol", referencedColumnName = "id_rol")
    )
    private Collection<Rol> roles;

    public Cliente() {
        super();
    }

    public Cliente(long id_cliente, @NotEmpty(message = "No puede estar vacío") String nombre,
        @NotEmpty(message = "No puede estar vacío") @Email(message = "Introduce una correcta dirección de correo") String correo,
        @NotEmpty(message = "No puede estar vacío") int tlf,
        @NotEmpty(message = "No puede estar vacío") String passwd,
        @NotEmpty(message = "No puede estar vacío") String confirm) {
        super();
        this.id_cliente = id_cliente;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.tlf = tlf;
        this.passwd = passwd;
        this.confirm = confirm;
    }

    public Cliente(long id_cliente, @NotEmpty(message = "No puede estar vacío") String nombre,
        @NotEmpty(message = "No puede estar vacío") @Email(message = "Introduce una correcta dirección de correo") String correo,
        @NotEmpty(message = "No puede estar vacío") int tlf,
        @NotEmpty(message = "No puede estar vacío") String passwd,
        @NotEmpty(message = "No puede estar vacío") String confirm, Collection<Rol> roles) {
        super();
        this.id_cliente = id_cliente;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.tlf = tlf;
        this.passwd = passwd;
        this.confirm = confirm;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public long getId_cliente() {
        return id_cliente;
    }

    public void setId_cliente(long id_cliente) {
        this.id_cliente = id_cliente;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public int getTlf() {
        return tlf;
    }

    public void setTlf(int tlf) {
        this.tlf = tlf;
    }

    public String getPasswd() {
        return passwd;
    }

    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    public String getConfirm() {
        return confirm;
    }

    public void setConfirm(String confirm) {
        this.confirm = confirm;
    }

    public Collection<Rol> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Rol> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.getCorreo();
    }

   @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.getPasswd();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

UserDetailsService:

```
public interface UserDetailsService {

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username);

}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepo;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        Cliente cliente = clienteRepo.findByCorreo(username);
        if (cliente == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return cliente;
    }
}
```